# Unable to run gazebo 1.0.0 RC2

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I have just installed Ubuntu and ROS and gazebo-1.0.0-RC2 but when I run the gzserver command this is what I get:

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.0-RC2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Warning: no world filename specified, using default world
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
Segmentation fault
```

Is there any log or anything else where I can try and figure out what's causing the Segmentation fault?

Previous to this I was having problems, gzserver repeated this message several times:

```
Xlib: extension “GLX” missing on display “:0.0″. Insufficient GL support
```

I solved it by installing OpenGL... and that's when the Segfault appeared. So now I don't know if this introduced the current error or it has nothing to do.

Thanks for your time!
Miguel.

---

---

Update:
My Ubuntu installation died and I had to reinstall everything... Now I'm not getting any Xlib errors or segfaults, but instead this is what's happening:

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.0-RC2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Warning: no world filename specified, using default world
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
Exception [RenderEngine.cc:473] unable to find rendering system

Error [Rendering.cc:37] Failed to load the Rendering engine subsystem
unable to find rendering system
Exception [RenderEngine.cc:473] unable to find rendering system

Exception [RenderEngine.cc:473] unable to find rendering system

Exception [Sensors.cc:38] Unable to load the rendering engine

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'gazebo::common::Exception'
Aborted
```

I'm going to investigate, but I wanted to post it here first.

Thanks again! Miguel.

---

---

Update 2:

I tried everything that I could think of, and I'm still getting those errors about the rendering system... Any ideas? :(

Thanks,
Miguel.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12947/unable-to-run-gazebo-1.0.0-rc2/) by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-02-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-02-12**:
(Weird... I accidentally double posted the comment and now I can't delete one without having the other deleted as well, so I'm editing this comment instead of deleting it. I think the problem is that the 6th comment is neither showed nor listed as "more comments").

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-02-12**:
BTW, I didn't understand very well what you said about the ros wrapped gazebo Hsu, because I don't have Fuerte installed (it's not listed as a requirement at gazebosim.org...). Right now I don't even have Electric or any other ros version!

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-02-12**:
I've updated the question after I've been forced to reinstall Ubuntu. Now I have a clean install of 11.10 with just the additional nVidia drivers and all the dependencies listed on the Requeriments page. And gazebo-1.0.0-RC2, of course.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-02-09**:
Can you make a backtrace?  There could be a problem in Fuerte that causes segfault with the ros wrapped gazebo.  Specifically when the plugin to get package paths is invoked (e.g. see https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk/gazebo/scripts/gazebo with the -p options).

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-02-09**:
For example, right now I am on a i5-650 @ 3.2GHz with 8GB of RAM and an ATI RV730 PRO (Radeon HD 4650)...

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-02-09**:
It's not that easy... Because I have Ubuntu 11.04 installed on a USB flash drive that I boot in different computers. And it doesn't work in any of the machines.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-02-08**:
Can you please add a description of your computer hardware?

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-02-22**:
can you post how you are starting gazebo?

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-02-22**:
Of course, I start gazebo by running 'gzserver', as indicated here: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/quick_start

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-02-22**:
also, did you install using deb, tarball or mercurial?

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-02-22**:
I used the .deb file. Should I try otherwise? :\

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-02-22**:
can you also post the output of 'glxinfo'?

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-02-23**:
Here you go: http://pastebin.com/bi8LUaiq

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-02-23**:
safe to say glx is not an issue.  Please double check to make sure your OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH points to where the ogre libraries are installed?

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-02-23**:
Hi, I'm not right now at the computer I use for all of these testings (e.g. glxinfo says "X Error of failed request..." in this machine), but I thought it wouldn't matter for something as simple as checking if a system variable points to the right location... correct me if I'm wrong. That said...

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-02-23**:
OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH doesn't point to where ogre libraries are, because it doesn't point anywhere... I can't test if these will solve the problem until tomorrow afternoon (~14h from now) because of the lack of GLX in these machine, but I'll update this as soon as I can. Thanks for your time! :)

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-02-23**:
I updated step 2 in http://gazebosim.org/wiki/quick_start, so it now says "source /usr/share/gazebo-[gazebo version]/setup.sh", which is more correct.

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-02-23**:
Anyway I thought that Gazebo didn't use OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH since C-Turtle... At least I think I read something about that somewhere :?

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-02-23**:
true if you install the ros wrapper version (install: http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu + "sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo" + http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials).  The instructions on gazebosim.org are for standalone system install, needs more setup.

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-02-23**:
Oh fuck, I didn't know that. Besides, don't you think it'd be a good idea to add these additional setup you are talking about to the gazebosim.org "quick start" and/or "install" guides? :-\

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-02-23**:
Oh wait! I didn't think that setup.sh would export OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH... AFTER running setup.sh I'd get this: http://pastebin.com/9pa5BL4S So I think I should modify setup.sh to point to /usr/lib/OGRE, am I wrong?

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-02-24**:
Yeah, after I changed the OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH to /usr/lib/OGRE everything seems to work fine. BTW, /usr/lib/OGRE was the default install dir for apt-get install libogre-dev... so maybe you should change (or just add) that path to the setup.sh in order to avoid this from happening to others :?

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-02-24**:
Oh, if you want to write the whole thing as an answer I'll gladly mark it as correct! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The instructions on [gazebosim.org](http://gazebosim.org) are for standalone system install of gazebo. (see my comment below about the ros-ified gazebo stack).  Your problem above might be fixed by the updated step 2 in [quick_start](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/quick_start)

```
source /usr/share/gazebo-[gazebo version]/setup.sh
```

should configure environment variables necessary for things to work correctly.  In this case, your system is missing the correct `OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH`.

On another note, it looks like you are trying to install gazebo simulator directly on your system (outside of ros context) for using it with ROS.  Let me try to clarify a little bit about the difference between the [ros simulator_gazebo stack](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo) and the [gazebosim project](http://gazebosim.org).

The [ros simulator_gazebo stack](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo) wraps a hand-picked stable version of gazebo from the [gazebo simulator project](http://gazebosim.org), and provides additional ros plugins/tools for using gazebo inside the ros environment.  By installing ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo, you don't have to worry about installing gazebo via instructions on gazebosim.org, but rather, just follow along the [ros wiki tutorials](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials).  However, if you are interested in helping out with testing/developing the underlying simulator software, then proceed with the system install as described on the [gazebo simulator project installation instruction page](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/install) and try out the [quick start steps](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/quick_start).  Note the two installs can exist side by side with some careful finessing of installation locations and system paths.

Hope this is not too confusing.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-03-02**:
@hsu if anyone installs ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo should they also install ros-fuerte-desktop*? and/or ros-electric-desktop? Also, the link you posted to the simulator_gazebo tutorials are way different than the ones at gazebosim... isn't ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo the same as gazebosim?

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-03-02**:
Ok, I figured it out myself, but please tell me if I'm right/wrong. In order to use the simulator as it's explained at the gazebosim wiki, one should source /setup.sh and then /stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/setup.bash. After that gzserver and gzclient work fine. (?)

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-03-02**:
sorry, I realized my earlier answer might be too confusing, so I removed the seconds part.  I'll try to put this information on gazebo wiki instead.  The basics are explained in the update gazebo package manifest (https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk/gazebo/manifest.xml)

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-03-02**:
Thanks! Anyway I decided to go with the ros-wrapped gazebo version because I think it'd be easier to upgrade :) So what I'm doing now is setting up the environment for ros-fuerte and for simulator_gazebo, and then I launch "rosrun gazebo gzserver" instead of gzserver directly ;-)

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-03-02**:
It's not confusing at all, don't worry. It's just I don't know what I really want to do, so I'm trying things out. What I want to accomplish is a Lego NXT simulator, and I thought it'd be a good idea to write plugins for gazebo (and use the NXT stack probably). So you tell me, do I want to use ROS?

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-03-02**:
I think I do want (and need?) to use it, and I'd like to use Fuerte and/or the newest gazebo, but I'm having problems with the whole 'lack of tutorials/documentation for these two' thing. Or maybe I'm just too clumsy to find them!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

###Update:###
The segmentation fault as described in [ticket:  compiler flag `-Bsymbolic-functions`](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3842) has been fixed, so

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to get the latest versions of ros and simulator_gazebo which do not have the boost related segmentation fault.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-02-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1